# Reducing width of a webpart impact width of other webpart too

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, css

Environment: SharePoint 2013

I`ve 2 WebParts created in SPS2013, in order to align the WebPart on my SharePoint homepage. I had set the width of WebPart 1 using CSS. However that impact the size of the other WebPart.

Reason - value: div.section-content-wrap (responsible for the body of the webpart) is set as the same value for both WebPart.

My CSS Code -

```
 div.section-content-wrap {
     height: 400px;
  }
```

Please suggest how can I just decrease or increase the height of content area for WebPart 1 only?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of HTML that represents the portion of the DOM the web parts are in? Based on your post, I can only gauge that both web parts match your `div.section-content-wrap` CSS rule; with seeing more of the markup, we can suggest a sufficiently unique selector that only gets applied to the one web part you want.

Comment: Learn to use CSS nth-child selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @Stevangelista please find the HTML code for Webpart 1 - News
http://imgur.com/PGMNSaF

HTML code for Webpart 2 - Events

http://imgur.com/WwJsaGZ

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP Wondering if the CSS code will be as below:

`code`
/* div.section-content.warp for webpart named NEWS */
p:nth-child(div.section-content-wrap) {
    height: 450px;
}


/* div.section-content.warp for webpart named EVENTS */
p:nth-child(div.section-content-wrap) {
    height: 400px;
}

`code`

Comment: @Jason - you need to show a larger snippet of code; your screenshot only shows up through the div with a class of section-content-wrap, which we already know is a shared class. Again, the goal would be to identify some parent element of the DIV you want to size that is different in some way so that a targeted CSS selector can be crafted.

Comment: Install a browser extension (like Stylish or StyleBot) so you can live edit CSS against a page

Comment: @Jason - unless you post the HTML of the actual SharePoint .aspx page, I cannot help. We understand you have two web parts with identical markup and you want one sized differently; this prohibits the use of the "section-content-wrap" class as your CSS selector. So either provide the HTML of the entire page so we can provide guidance on crafting a suitable CSS selector, or in your code apply inline styles on the one web part you want to customize. FWIW, SharePoint web parts also have a height & width web part property, eliminating the need for height & width CSS if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery so that it works in all browsers.

On document ready assign the height only to first Div of required type. 
The below function will go inside your webpart 1 ASCX file. 
Add a Jquery reference before the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
         $("div.section-content-wrap:first").css("height", "400px");
} );
```

Same can be achieved using CSS selectors but it will work on modern browsers only which comply with CSS3 standards

Comment: I tried with the code but that didn't worked, please check if my code is correct and if any change is needed.


`code`

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()  {
         $("div.section-content-wrap:first").css("height", "200px");
} );

</script>

`code`

Comment: The OP doesn't explicitly state that there are only two DIV elements on the page with a class of "section-content-wrap" - only that he has two web parts using that class. Also, depending on page layout, the one he's trying to size may not necessarily be the first in the DOM tree. Finally, the CSS3 pseudo-selector :first-child is supported back to IE9, Safari 3.2 and all versions of Chrome & Firefox. It's use is much preferred over loading jQuery for such a basic CSS use case.

Comment: @Stevangelista please find the Complete DIV element for the 2 - 

Pasting code is going to high so showing code as an image.
Img link: http://imgur.com/lwKyETt

I tried using the following CSS to modify the height for a specific class - 

`code`
.section-content-wrap:nth-last-child(odd)
{
    height: 300px;
}

//OR

.section-content-wrap:first-child
{
    height: 450px;
}

`code`

none worked.

Pls help

Comment: @Stevangelista: Agreed. Writing it in CSS will have less foot print.       Jason: Check in your DEV tools and see whether the styles are over-written. Try using !important in your CSS declarations. Now coming to the JQuery code, put a alert or debug it to see whether it fires in the first place & see the value of $("div.section-content-wrap").length while debugging the above code. It should be more than 1

Comment: Can u share some article? Is the jquery code I've inserted based on ur inputs, is it fine?

Comment: @Stevangelista pls assist with the CSS code

Comment: @Anand researching further more, found the code from other site that may work and would like to confirm as its on jquery side.
`code`
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()  {
         $("div.section-content-wrap:first").css('height`,setHeight+`200px !important`);

</script>
`code`

Comment: If it works it works :-) @jason

Comment: @Stevangelista any suggestions?

Comment: @Jason, see my last comment on the OP. I'm happy to try & help but you haven't provided sufficient information for me to do so.

Comment: @Stevangelista, on the same lines. I have set an  internal border for class name: class="ms-vb2"

Comment: @Stevangelista, on the same lines. I have set an  internal border for class name: class="ms-vb2"

Again this class is common for 2 webparts, therefore CSS - 


/* Home.aspx (1164, 12) */
td.ms-vb2 {
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: black;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}


Above is applied using CSS only for the homepage.

Please suggest how can i remove the border for one webpart.

webpart entire HTML code - 

http://imgur.com/IiBVojl